# difference between "has been too lonely" and "is too lonely"

Tags: difference, perfect-constructions

I read lyrics of *Some Say Love/The Rose* and then a question came up in my mind which is little bit unclear for me.

What is the exact differences between

> When the night, **has been** too lonely,...

and

> When the night, **is** too lonely,...

Like again I have an idea about what the difference might be but I would glad to hear an explanation from a native.

The section of the [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bettemidler/therose.html) where this appears is:

*When the night, has been too lonely,

And the road, has been too long.

And you feel, that love is only,

for the lucky, and the strong.*

Comment: The *has been* usage suggests that the discussion is about something that has past. The *is* version is generally used to talk about a habit. For instance, *when the night is too lonely, I go for drinks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a theory, but I believe it might provide some further understanding. Simply put, the collocation “has been” seems as though it is the *present-tense* phrasal verb to denote *relating to the past*; on the contrary, “is” emphasises its occurrence as a *present event*.

For example, consider the following two examples:

> *It has been such a lovely day so far*, the teenager mused; even as she spoke, the day-star rayed down its comforting warmth, bathing her in golden light . . .

> “It’s beautiful today, isn’t it?” he asked his companion, eyes momentarily hovering over the form of a pre-teen girl, his junior by only several months. As he spoke, sunlight refracted off of her cerulean eyes, causing them to appear as though they were sparkling; the light also glanced off of her short, reddish-orange hair . . .

In the first example, the term “has been” refers to something earlier (in this case, the time period), although it may, at times, extend to the current happenings—but chiefly as a supplement.

However, the subsequent example indicates the present occurrences, in present tense.